# Is it ok for the one output of a dual-channel op-amp into an input of the other channel on the same IC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

So I have an LM358 op-amp with 2 (as far as I'm aware) separate channels. I need to increase gain but also need to have enough current to activate a diode. The problem is that the device (sensor) whose voltage I will be amplifying cannot source enough current to activate the diode. So I would use another op-amp with a gain of 1 just as a current buffer. Luckily (or perhaps not), the op-amp I'm using has another channel sitting right there unused.

Can I save board space by having the output of channel 1 go (not directly) to one of the inputs of channel 2? Or will this type of feedback mess up the operation of the device? Note that their inputs will not be connected, nor will their outputs, only the output of one to the input of the other.

Comment: In general - there should not be a problem. But you better post your proposed circuit schematic.

Comment: Connecting opamps in series does not increase the maximum output current, instead it can increase the voltage gain. The second opamp will have exactly the same maximum output current as the first opamp. For more output current you can use an audio  power amplifier IC.

Comment: "Activate a diode" what do you mean by that exactly? Do you want to power an LED connected with the output of the opamp? Modern high efficiency indicator LEDs (plenty of them on Amazon, for example --  no-brand kind, but very good for hobby projects) will blind your eyes with just a few milliamperes, which an LM358 output can easily provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is minimal interaction between the channels on an LM358. Easily detectable, but microvolts.

For most ordinary purposes you can treat them as two separate op-amps with common power pins and common thermal considerations.